# How to collapse rows by identical values in a column

Tags: r

Good evening,
I have a two columns tab separated .txt file, as the following:

```
number  letter  
1   a
1   b
2   a
2   b
3   b
```

I would like to collapse rows where the column "number" has identical value, by creating a comma separated value in the corresponding column "letter".
In other words, this should be the output:

```
number  letter
1   a,b
2   a,b
3   b
```

I have looked up the web but I did not find an actual solution.

Thank you in advance,
Giuseppe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `aggregate` in `base R`

```
aggregate(letter ~ number, df1, FUN = paste, collapse=",")
```

-output

```
#   number letter
#1      1    a,b
#2      2    a,b
#3      3      b
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(number) %>%
     summarise(letter = str_c(letter, collapse=","))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(number = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), letter = c("a", 
"b", "a", "b", "b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also combine `aggregate()` with `toString`:

```
#Code
newdf <- aggregate(letter~.,df,toString)
```

Output:

```
  number letter
1      1   a, b
2      2   a, b
3      3      b
```

Some data:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(number = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), letter = c("a", 
"b", "a", "b", "b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```